# How to change change duration of flutter animations package OpenContainer() widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to Use to OpenContainer() Widget in my app and my app requires varying animation speeds for both closing and opening the OpenContainer() widget is it possible to change it dynamically or specify it

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/master/packages/animations/lib/src/open_container.dart#L233

Comment: yap I already notices that i tried using two open widgets simultaneously but it throws an error

Comment: Can you post some code here?

Answer (score 2):

`OpenContainer` Widget have a `transitionDuration` property that can be set to desired duration for animation.

```
   OpenContainer(
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
      closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
      ),
      closedBuilder: (context, action) => CloseWidget(),
      openBuilder: (context, action) => OpenWidget(),
    );
```

You can do further reading [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/OpenContainer-class.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea how to change openBuilder and closeBuilder duration seperately?